# Zend custom form validator 'NOT FOUND'

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am stuck in the follow situation. To check a url with zend_form, I have to add a custom validator. I try to add the custom validator named 'IsUrl.php' in;

***What I do now***

I add IsUrl.php to;

```
Library/Lib/Validate/
```

In my boodstrap:

```
protected function _initLibAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Lib',
            'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
            ));

    return $autoloader;
}
```

Test in Controller by;

```
$test = new Zend_Validate();
$test = new Lib_Validate_IsUrl();
```

Fatal error;

```
Fatal error: Class 'Lib_Validate_IsUrl' not found in
```

Thanks in advice.

With kind regards,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to tell ZF, that you have custom validators :) You could adjust your bootstrap like this:

```
protected function _initValidators () {
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader (array ('namespace' => '', 'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
    $autoloader->addResourceType ('Validator', 'validators', 'Validator_');
}
```

Comment: Isn't better to keep validators like this in the library folder? Like library/My/Validator/IsUrl.php in this case?

Comment: You can store them where ever you want. The question was why ZF can't find the validator and not where to store it :)

Comment: Kees Schepers, yes. You have a point there, I know. But First I need this thing working. entek, It's logical to let the bootstrap know, thanks for that but still the same fatal error :(..

Comment: As your write above, you've moved your validator to `Library/Lib/Validate`. You must adapt the autoloader to your changes. Try the following: 

`$autoloader->addResourceType ('Validator', 'Lib/Validate', 'Lib_Validator_');`